# When is a matrix with repeated eigenvalues diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let $A_{n\times n}$ have $0<k \leq n$ repeated eigenvalues. Is there any condition that I can impose on $A$, that guarantees that it is diagonalizable? That is, I'm looking for conditions on $A$ which are broad enough to allow repeated eigenvalues, but constrained enough to ensure that there are $k$ linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to the $k$ repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: A symmetric matrix will always be diagonalizable, even with repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: More generally a [normal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) is always diagonalizable. But in fact the density of non-diagonalizable matrices is zero, so if you use a random generator for matrix elements, the matrix will be almost sure diagonolizable.

Comment: @user: Thank you! I guess this was what I was looking for.

Comment: Suppose that $\lambda$ is repeated $k$ times, then one should have Nullity$ (A-\lambda I) =k$.

Comment: if there are special properties you know about the matrix, that should be mentioned.  E.g. a Companion Matrix is never diagonalizable if it has a repeated eigenvalue.

Comment: $A$ is diagonalizable iff the minimal polynomial factors into the product of distinct monomials.